# Error en búsqueda de ficheros por tiempo en un script

Tags: bash, script, find

necesitamos realizar un script que nos diga si hay ficheros que tengan más de una hora desde su creación en una carpeta determinada. He probado con el siguiente script pero me da error:

```
#!/bin/bash
BUSQUEDA=`find /data/transaction -type f -mmin +60`
echo $BUSQUEDA
if [ `echo $BUSQUEDA` == ""];then
        echo "false"
        exit 0
else
        echo "true"
        exit 2
fi

[root@maquinalinux ~]$ bash ficheros_*

ficheros_transactions.sh: line 11: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

También he probado con lo siguiente que no da error en https://www.shellcheck.net/ y nada. Sigue lanzando el mismo error.

```
#!/bin/bash
BUSQUEDA=$(find /data/transaction -type f -mmin +60)
if [ "$BUSQUEDA" == "" ];then
        echo "false"
else
        echo "true"
fi
```

Comment: Simplemente usa `[ -z "$variable" ]` o directamente `[ -z "$(find ...)" ]`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido de gran ayuda. Con el siguiente comando solucionado:
[ -z $(find /rhapsody4/rhapsody/data/transaction -type f -mmin +60) ] && echo "false" || echo "true"

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucionado con el siguiente comando.

```
#!/bin/bash
[ -z $(find /data/transaction -type f -mmin +60) ] && echo "false" || echo "true"
```